# Using Steam WebAPI to get total time playing a game

Tags: python, steam-web-api

I'm trying to get access to the amount of TF2 time played using the Steam API. I'm currently using:-

```
http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=440&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&steamid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&format=xml
```

And then filter through the XML and extracting the time played relating to each of the classes (e.g. pyro (Pyro.accum.iPlayTime), etc). This worked ok but I think missing the MVM classes made my final value incorrect (my code, in Python, returned 977 when online sites say over 1600 hours). Adding the MVM classes (plus possibly others) may provide th ecorrect result but it's making the code very long winded.

So I was wondering if there is a call in the Steam Web API that will just give me the total time played without having to go though all the extracting and adding?

I have looked through the Steam Web API Developer page, but can't find any reference to what I'm after.

Added Code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import urllib2
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    import datetime

    timeKISA = 0
    playerStatsKISA = urllib2.urlopen('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=440&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&steamid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&format=xml')
    statsKISA = playerStatsKISA.read()
    theStatsKISA = ET.fromstring(statsKISA)
    for stat in theStatsKISA.findall("./stats/stat"):
        if stat.find('name').text.startswith('Scout.accum.iPlayTime') or \
             stat.find('name').text.startswith('Soldier.accum.iPlayTime') or \
             stat.find('name').text.startswith('Engineer.accum.iPlayTime') or \
             stat.find('name').text.startswith('Medic.accum.iPlayTime') or \
             stat.find('name').text.startswith('Spy.accum.iPlayTime') or \
             stat.find('name').text.startswith('Sniper.accum.iPlayTime') or \
             stat.find('name').text.startswith('Demoman.accum.iPlayTime') or \
             stat.find('name').text.startswith('Heavy.accum.iPlayTime') or \
             stat.find('name').text.startswith('Pyro.accum.iPlayTime'):

             timeKISA = timeKISA + int(stat.find('value').text) 
        finalTimeKISA = timeKISA / 60 / 60
        KISATime = ('KISA_Time=' + str(finalTimeKISA) + ' hours')
        print KISATime
```

Thank you.

Markus

Comment: @Andy, Thanks for the reply Andy. Which iPlayTime's do you add? Obviously all the ones relating to the classes (i.e Pyro, Engie, Medic, etc). Do you also need to include all the MvM equivalent classes? I also noticed there are iPlaytime tags that relate to maps as well, which I assume I do not include. I believe I could get the correct value if I added all the relevant iPlayTime, but my question is more focused on if there is a simpler way to get the total time, e.g. a tag that is simply iTotalPlayTime? I'll try to add my code above (having never done it before :) )

Comment: @Andy, my profile is 76561197960964581. The code returns me a total of 987 hours, but when I look at somewhere like TF2Stats, it's telling me I'm over 1600 hours.

Comment: @Andy, Thanks Andy, I'll leave it at that then and assume the Classes include both normal and mvm maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulling my comments into an answer,

It is my understanding that the `*.accum.iPlayTime` fields are cumulative for your place time as that class regardless of game mode or map. Based on my own stats (and a glance at a few others on my friend list), this matches exactly what Steam Community reports that play time is. Additionally, it is reporting that your playtime matches these fields on your TF2 Achievements page.

A couple notes:

- The summary page on a player's profile does not seem to match the actual stats that the achievements page shows. I'm unsure if this is a Steam Community issue or a summary of additional fields. However, the achievements page, which has detailed break downs of play time by class, longest life, etc. is using the same data as the `GetUserStatsForGame` API call.
- You have a very minor formating issue in your code. The very last `print KISATime` is indented one to many times and therefore prints the `KISA_Time =` line multiple times. If you pull it out of the `for` loop, you will only get the print line once.
- If you change your `finalTimeKISA = timeKISA / 60 / 60` to be decimal `60.0` you will get the decimal answers. Otherwise, as is, you will only receive an integer answer.

Comment: Thanks for writing that all up and with more clarification. The indent was a mistake as part of shortening my code for this question (my full code includes a number of accounts and saves the results to file for logging. But thanks for pointing it out. I will also add the decimal point for more accuracy. Thanks again.