# Steam Web API - Unit Of Time Unspecified?

Tags: time, steam-web-api

I'm starting to dive into the Steam web API a bit. I'm pulling my stats for a game I play and just tinkering around, I see in the array the following

```
{
    "name": "total_time_played",
    "value": 3067447
}
```

I know that in this game I have exactly 1451 Hours played. I tried seconds to hours, so on so forth. My main question being. What unit of time is this recorded in? I have scoured the steam developer forums to see if anyone has an answer but no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Steam began tracking total playtime in early 2009. If your account is older than that, the API results will be inaccurate.

This is from their [documentation](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API)  (Ctrl+F "total playtime")

The documentation says it is in minutes, but [previous experience](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19769779/189134) says that it is in seconds.

This comes up to 852 hours, which is entirely reasonable if you have had this account since before 2009 and were fairly active in the game you are checking playtime.